# detect strings starting with numbers

Tags: php, regex

I explored internet but couldn't find an example.
And I have really problem about understanding regular expressions.
**I want to have a regular expression condition which checks if a String starts with Numbers.**
How can I do that in PHP?

thanks in advance

Comment: Quite ironic `I explored internet`. Anyways you clearly need to learn regex. You may learn it from [here](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/) or [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or even from the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php), fiddle it [here](http://regex101.com) and when you get stuck search it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+regex).

Comment: In this case, to check if the first character of a string is a digit character is better accomplished using language constructs instead of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php

$string = "42foobar";

if (preg_match("/^\d/", $string)) {
    echo "string match was found.";
} else {
    echo "string match was not found.";
}
?>
```

- `^` means *start of string*
- `\d` means a digit

Comment: You mean *digit*, not *number*.  A number implies any type of numerical value, including negative numbers, which it will not match.  A digit signifies a single numeral, typically from 0-9.  Your scenario only accounts for non-negative real numbers.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: And the award for pedantry goes to @BLaZuRE! ;-) Seriously though, +1 you're right.

Comment: For what it's worth, ^-?(\.\d|\d) will pick up on whether the string starts with negative and positive numbers. That is, assuming you're not interested in complex numbers too.

Comment: Just because I was told I was being pedantic, you might be missing the `+` in your RegEx.  *I think* it's left out since it's implied, but it's possible to have a number be `+42`. not just `-42`.  I'm not a mathematician so I might be wrong.  Also, it doesn't catch numbers like 3.14.  I'd do `^(+|-)?\d*\.?\d+` for base 10 real numbers.  Note, that allows zero to be denoted as positive or negative.  Sorry I was bored =D.